# Custom fields multiple commas separated values

Tags: custom-field

This code is working fine but when I add multiple commas separated values in custom fields value then It's not working. (Example:- Demo, Demo Two)

```
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
if ($Style_Cabinet_Style)
 {
    $meta_query[] =  array(
        'meta_key' => 'Cabinet_Style',
        'value' => $Style_Cabinet_Style,
        'compare' => 'IN'
        );



$query = new WP_Query(
array( 
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supposed to. If you want to use multiple values in an `IN` meta query you need to pass an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). That would look like this:

```
$Style_Cabinet_Style = array( 'Demo', 'Demo Two' );
```

If you only have a String with commas separating the values, eg. `'Demo, Demo Two'`. Then you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the values into an array using commas:

```
$Style_Cabinet_Style = 'Demo, Demo Two'; // Assuming

$values = explode( ',', $Style_Cabinet_Style );
$values = array_map( 'trim', $values );
```

The `array_map()` line is running the `trim()` function on all the values in the array. This removes whitespace from the beginning and end of the value. This ensures that any spaces between the commas, eg. `'One, Two, Three'` are removed after splitting into an array, otherwise you'd end up with:

```
$values = array( 'Demo', ' Demo Two' );
```

Once you've done that you can pass the values to the meta query:

```
$meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

if ( $Style_Cabinet_Style ) {
    $values = explode( ',', $Style_Cabinet_Style );
    $values = array_map( 'trim', $values );

    $meta_query[] =  array(
        'meta_key' => 'Cabinet_Style',
        'value'    => $values,
        'compare'  => 'IN'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query(
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'gallery',
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hii @jacob, 
Thanks for your help. I tried your codes it but 'value' is not matching multiple commas separated values by custom fields.

Comment: See how I put multiple values (http://prntscr.com/li9kpe).

Comment: Well that's not multiple values. That's just a value with a comma in it. You can't query inside values like that.